# Unordered List Won't Center Align

Tags: html, css, centering

h1 seems to have no trouble centering, however, the list (menu bar) will not align, it seems to be indented slightly. Please explain.

My HTML:

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
```

My CSS:

```
h1{
text-align: center;
}

ul{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  list-style: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px; 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still default padding on the `ul` element.
Change the CSS of your `ul` to this and it'll work:

```
ul{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  list-style: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```