# Text-align:center For Unordered List Looks Off When Screen Is Minimised

Tags: html, css, html-lists, text-align

When using `text-align:center` in HTML, the following `<ul>` element looks a bit off when the screen is minimised. It looks like it's biased toward the right.

How can I make this list more responsive?

```html
    <div>
      <p style="text-align:center;">
        We're able to provide expertise across the entire IT and business spectrum, particularly in:
      </p>
      <br>
      <ul style="text-align:center;list-style:none">
        <li>Sportsbook and Data Services</li>
        <li>Cloud Services Migration</li>
        <li>Excel and VBA Enterprise Management</li>
        <li>Financial Services</li>
        <li>Mathematical Modelling</li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <p style=" text-align:center;">E-mail enquiries@sabg.co.uk to find out how we can help you lower your development costs and increase your output. <a href="mailto:info@sabg.co.uk"></a>
      </p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `padding: 0;` for your ul element;

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've managed to find the answer, [Unordered List Won't Center Align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025008/unordered-list-wont-center-align), 
I think this CSS does it:

```
ul{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```